# Num rows returns wrong number

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

Im trying to count the rows where there are 0 rows, but it return 1 row anyways, when there are no rows that matches the SQL query. Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

```
        $del = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_GET['del']));

    if ($del)
    {
        $sql6 = "SELECT count(*) FROM oneliners WHERE id='$del' AND to_user='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
        $result6 = mysql_query($sql6) or trigger_error(mysql_error()."".$sql6);
        $num_rows6 = mysql_num_rows($result6);

        echo $sql6;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $num_rows6;

        //If no rows return, do this
        if ($num_rows6 <= 0)
        {
            header("location:oneliner.php");
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: You are already using count(*) so it will always return 1 row.

Comment: You need to escape that `$_SESSION[]` as well. All superglobals that you inject into an sql-statement need escaping.

Answer (score 4):

The query always return one row. The row contains the count of rows. You should rather use [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) than [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), where the latter one count the number of rows returned by the query.

```
$sql6 = "SELECT count(*) FROM oneliners WHERE id='$del' AND to_user='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$result6 = mysql_query($sql6) or trigger_error(mysql_error()."".$sql6);
if($num_rows6 = mysql_fetch_row($result6)) {
   echo $num_rows6[0]; // Prints the number of rows
}
```

---

Even though the easiest way to fix your problem would be to change your query to be:

```
$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM oneliners WHERE id='$del' AND to_user='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

I'd highly recommend to use the first alternative because this easier way will return ALL rows and thus be less efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You are counting already in sql query. That's returning always one row. Even if there's zero rows in database table. There's two ways of doing it:

1. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` and that's it. No more need for `mysql_num_rows()` function. If all you want to do is get a count of rows then this way is quicker.
2. `SELECT * FROM ...` and you can use `mysql_num_rows()` function. If you want to get all the rows anyway for displaying in a table and also count them, then this is a way to go.